# installing PSWindows Update non-interactively

Tags: powershell

I'm running a command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Confirm:$false -Force;Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate;Get-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB5035845 -Install -IgnoreReboot
```

and regardless what I can think of, terminal keeps asking me for user input, I just want everything to be automatically accepted so I can push this command onto hundreds of devices.

I tried adding

```
-Confirm:$false
```

at the end of each script and still nothing. As you can see from the image below.

[image]

Comment: Install the nuget provider first like it says.